# How to declare Kendo UI object in AngularJS directive link

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have the following kendoDatePicker included in an AngularJS directive; the directive is supposed to show the picker opening the calendar but it doesn't. What's wrong with this code? [This is the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/RfHQqDv8boJJrFSpbW5H?p=preview).

HTML:

```
<dir2></dir2>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [ "kendo.directives" ]);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {

}



app.directive('dir2', function() {

     var directive = {};

     directive.restrict = 'A';

     directive.template = '<input kendo-date-picker="picker" />';

     directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) { 

         scope.picker.open();

     };

   return directive;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

where it says

```
    scope.picker.open();
```

it should say

```
    $timeout(function() {  
          scope.picker.open();
    }, 1);
```

Comment: You do not need 100 ms. You just need to push it to the next digest cycle s that the template is rendered during the previous.

Answer (score 0):

You should define directive.restrict = 'E' instead of 'A'.

'A' refers for attribute, 'E' for element.

```
app.directive('dir2', function() {

     var directive = {};

     directive.restrict = 'E';

     directive.template = '<input kendo-date-picker="picker" />';

     directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) { 

         scope.picker.open();

     };

   return directive;
});
```

Comment: oops... fixed it but it's still not working, I get `Cannot read property 'open' of undefined` [see plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/RfHQqDv8boJJrFSpbW5H?p=preview)

Comment: What are trying to open by scope.picker.open() ?

Comment: It's just an example.  scope.picker.open()  should open up a calendar for date selection. My issue is that scope.picker is undefined, and I cannot get the object handle in the directive.

Comment: This is what I found: scope.picker exists only after the directive is initialized. [In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/E6eOcm2RikUGDn0TbYLO?p=preview)  you can see that scope.picker2.open throws an error, while scope.picker.open, inside a method called after initialization, works fine.